# Compute $[\mathbb{I}-z\mathbb{P}]^{-1}$

Tags: z-transform

Unfortunately, I missed some classes and I cannot find information about z-transformation in my book, so I hope somebody can help me!
This is an exercise, but I do not have to know the answer, I just want to know how this kind of exercises work and what the z-transform exactly is.

Consider a Markov chain with a two-symbol alphabet and transition matrix 
$$\mathbb{P}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{2}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \end{pmatrix} $$
Prove that $$[\mathbb{I}-z\mathbb{P}]^{-1}= \frac{1}{1-z} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{4}{9} & \frac{5}{9} \\ \frac{4}{9} & \frac{5}{9} \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}z} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{4}{9} & -\frac{5}{9} \\ -\frac{4}{9} & \frac{5}{9} \end{pmatrix}$$

Again, I do not have to know the complete proof, I just want help with the following:

- What do they mean with two-symbol alphabet?
- why do they use $[\mathbb{I}-z\mathbb{P}]^{-1}$ to compute eventually the nth power of $\mathbb{P}$?
- How do I start to prove this? Can you give me a hint how to begin?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: diagonalize $P$, hence $P = Q D Q^{-1}$ and $I-z P = Q (I-z D) Q^{-1}$, hence $(I -z P)^{-1}= Q (I-z D)^{-1} Q^{-1}$

Comment: and do you know what is a Markov chain ? look at this : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-u9XslQrACb8/VK71Cym3zQI/AAAAAAAAAA0/DAxkKTcCKvc/s1600/markovdiag.png the probability for each day that the weather is sunny, cloudy or rainy (here 3 symbols) is modelized by a Markov chain. if a day it is sunny, the day after the probability that it is sunny or cloudy or rainy is given by the transition matrix (the weights of the arrows of the graph)....

Comment: I do now what a Markov Chain is :) I'm now diagonalizing, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've found the eigenvalues 1/10 and 1, but that's not the same as P. Do I have to take D as the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{10} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: aah I've found it! Thanks for your help!